# XGBClassifier default scoring metric

Tags: cross-validation, python, multi-class, boosting, scoring-rules

I am working with pythons xgboost `XGBClassifier` on a multiclass classification problem.

I am trying to interpret the score that sklearns `cross_val_score` returns

What is the default scoring metric use by XGBClassifier for multiclass classification tasks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same project using XGboost as well. For scoring metric in XGboost you can go for 'binary:logistics' as the objective function and 'logloss' as the eval_metric. This is because the ultimate goal for credit defaulters prediction is to maximise the separation between good and bad defaulters hence using 'logloss' aligns with this objective.

For your question, cross_val_score is score basis on what eval_metric that you choose. Hope this helps.